# Multi staged docker setup which is mainly used for building cpp dependencies from source

Tags: docker, docker-multi-stage-build

I am currently struggeling to come up with an optimal dockerfile structure that lets me do the building of all my cpp dependencies in one of the base images(because they are rarely updated) and then have more frequently updated apt packages and such in images that build from base. I cannot seem to make a multi staged dockerfile that when ran, recognizes that the base image has no changes so it uses the one already on my pc/pulls from dockerhub and then proceeds to rebuild the next images that have some changes. Any advice on how my setupo should look like? thanks

Comment: What does your current setup look like, and what problems are you running into?  Superficially I'd expect it to look like, say, a typical Go multi-stage build, where a first stage `RUN make` or something similar and the final stage `COPY --from` its results, but there are a lot of different variations especially in C++ build systems.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.